# Loadrunner correlation issue

Tags: loadrunner

I am facing following issues with loadrunner script.[WEB HTTP]

Issue1:
I need to capture the 7ffdce2b value from "tcollaborators7c0202c71508||~1fc~-7ffdce0f||collaborator_role" string in loadrunner.
tcollaborators7c0202c71508 this value is dynamic and changes with every iteration and there are multiple values if I use the right boundary ||~1fc~ and left boundary ||collaborator_role

Issue 2:
The page view for the response does not show the complete page properly. How to view the page similar to recording snapshot display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Capture the whole string, " "tcollaborators7c0202c71508||~1fc~-7ffdce0f||collaborator_role"
2. With your language determine where the first incident of "-" occurs.  Trim off the left substring
3. With your choice of language on the remaining string, "7ffdce0f||collaborator_role" look for the incidence of '||'
4. Capture the substring from the start of your trimmed string to the length where your '||' string occurs

Comment: Thanks James for the solution